# Need help with regex Email in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list with contacts each line, we have to replace the whole line in to single email:

Name, Surname, Address, Email, Phone
=>
Email

I know how to find email, but I need smth like find and replace to "" everything but Email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your email regular expression is well-written and won't match anything that isn't an email...

Find (`()` characters are significant):

```
^.*(your email regex here).*$
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me using Notepad++ to remove everything except for the email addresses:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up Find/Replace dialog box.
2. Change to the the Replace tab.
3. Find what:   `^.*(\<[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z]?\>).*$`
4. Replace with: `\1`
5. You need to select `[Regular Expression]` at the bottom of the Find/Replace dialog box.
6. Then click `[Replace All]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can replace "everything except" any regex in notepad++. I usually use macros for such a problem.

But another method would it be, to import the data into Excel as a CSV, mark the column with the email adresses and copy-paste them to notepad++. That's another trick I usually do.

Comment: this trick will work, still would like to some regex in action

Comment: You can use regex, but not for that specific problem.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering about this. It is possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458392/1926621