# Delete all lines (not) matching a regex using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to delete all lines matching or not matching a regex in Notepad++?

In Vim, I'd do the following to delete all matching lines:

```
:g/regex/d
```

And to delete all non matching lines:

```
:!g/regex/d
```

I'm looking for these commands' equivalent in Notepad++.

As also explained in "[Notepad++ - delete all lines with certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472052/notepad-delete-all-lines-with-certain-text)", I usually go for the approach of blanking the matching lines and deleting the blank lines afterwards. Is there a simpler way?

---

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185998/1698309), versions of Notepad++ >= 6.0 support matching line breaks in regex, thus allowing to delete whole lines directly without creating blank lines first. The following pattern should remove all lines containing "foobar" when replaced with an empty string:

```
^.*foobar.*\r\n
```

Now, as discussed in "[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)", negating regular expressions isn't exactly straightforward. Deleting lines in Notepad++ which do not contain "foobar" would require the following pattern:

```
^((?!foobar).)*\r\n
```

Because that's a quite complicated command to type just for removing lines which don't contain a word (or possibly more complex expression), I wonder if there is an easier solution.

Comment: Are you interested in 1-step solution only? There is another solution, an unroll-the-loop one: `^[^f\n]*(?:f(?!oobar)[^f\n]*)*(?:\R|$)`, but again it might look "complicated".

Comment: I'm interested in the solution which takes the fewest keystrokes/clicks. :)

Comment: Then, I guess, you have a solution below.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the `Find` (`Ctrl + F` or `Search > Find`) dialog, on the `Mark` tab, you can `Bookmark lines` that match.

[image: mark ui]

Then use the menu item `Search > Bookmark > Remove Non-Bookmarked Lines`  or  `Remove Bookmarked lines`.

[image: menu layout]

Comment: This is probably fastest way to do it in Notepad++. :)

Comment: yeah that's a great way to do it!

Comment: I have matched some part of each line so this doesnt work for me

Comment: This is SO Gold!

Comment: for those finding this now, you need to check "Bookmark line" checkbox for this to work. @UmairAyub

Comment: If I could upvote twice I would! Super easy to do, but I always forget that the `Remove Unmarked Lines` is inside the `Search` menu

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it just saved me so much work!