# Notepad++ delete lines at an interval (e.g. with Skip and Take)

Tags: notepad++

I would like to keep the 1st minQty, maxQty, stepSize but delete the 2nd minQty, maxQty, stepSize. A possible solution in C# would be to take 5 lines and then skip 3 lines. Is there something like this in Notepad++.

Normally i would solve this by bookmarking lines containing a certain strings and then deleting the unbookmarked lines like this ([Delete all lines (not) matching a regex using Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458344/delete-all-lines-not-matching-a-regex-using-notepad)). But here this won't work since the strings are the same.

```
"symbol": "ETHBTC",
                "filterType": "LOT_SIZE",
                "minQty": "0.00100000",
                "maxQty": "100000.00000000",
                "stepSize": "0.00100000"
                "minQty": "0.00000000",
                "maxQty": "9201.00570633",
                "stepSize": "0.00000000"
"symbol": "LTCBTC",
                "filterType": "LOT_SIZE",
                "minQty": "0.01000000",
                "maxQty": "100000.00000000",
                "stepSize": "0.01000000"
                "minQty": "0.00000000",
                "maxQty": "33144.83294363",
                "stepSize": "0.00000000"
```

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: You could include all seven lines of each record in the regex and use capture groups to replace only the last three.

Comment: You could capture what you want to keep and match the 3 lines after that to remove them https://regex101.com/r/ydk8Dt/1

Comment: Check this on how to back reference captured groups: https://riptutorial.com/notepadplusplus/example/27189/referencing-capture-groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could capture the lines in a group that you want to keep, starting with filterType and the next 3 lines. Then match the 3 lines after it that you want to remove.

In the replacement use the first capturing group `$1`

```
("filterType":\h+"LOT_SIZE",(?:\R\h+"[^"]+":\h+"[^"]+",?){3})(?:\R\h+"[^"]+":\h+"[^"]+",?){3}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ydk8Dt/1/)

[image]

Comment: Thats really interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

Find what: `filter((.*\n){4})[\s\S]*?step.*\s?`
Replace with: `$1`

Or this,  both are working for me...

Find what: `filter[\s\S]*?step.*\K[\s\S]*?step.*?"`
Replace with: `nothing`